# How to run one of the jsp statement in if or else block within javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm trying to gave a jsp statement, in a if/else javascript block. Here is my current code

```
int st=2;
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      if(confirm("Table Already Exists. Do you want to update")==true)  {
        <% st=1;%>
     } else {                      
        document.write("else block");
        <% st=0;%>
        }
```

it gives st=0 answer

Answer (score 0):

java script for client(browser) side and jsp for server side, so you cant do the condition like this.

you can use hidden parameter and hold this value

```
       if(confirm("Table Already Exists. Do you want to update")==true)  {
     document.getElementById('someId').value =1;
 } else {                      
    document.write("else block");
               document.getElementById('someId').value =0;
    }

    in jsp

      <input type="hidden" name="someId" id="someId" />
```

in server side by using you can get the value
          request.getParameter("someId")